# How do you input all txt files in a directory into an array?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know **how you put all the txt files within a folder into array**, also if possible-->  I'm anticipating  the numbers of files to change so please consider a dynamic array or just simply copying and pasting into another array that fits all elements(file names in this case) into that array  .this is so I manipulate the order of elements(files in this case)

I searched through other questions with C# tag but since i'm new i can't understand or translate concept into vb.

Comment: DO you mean you want to read the file names into an array, or the file content into an array ?

Comment: sorry, I meant read the file names

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System.IO;

...

string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "*.txt");
```

Cheers

EDIT oops... I keep getting bitten by this. Answering C# to VB.NET tagged questions.

VB.NET:

```
Dim dirs As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\", "*.txt")
```

Comment: Dim Files As New Directory
        Files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories) however return an error msg saying it can't convert array string into system.io.directory

Comment: Please read the documentation. GetFiles doesn't return a Directory